# Why does this simple Hydra command not work despite the writeup specifying the exact same syntax?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-mojave, hydra

So lately I have been trying to learn hydra from [tryhackme](https://www.tryhackme.com/room/hydra), and tried to use this simple command

`hydra -l molly  -P /Users/root/Desktop/ctf/rockyou.txt 10.10.161.247  http-form-post "/:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F=incorrect" -V`

But it does not work and shows

```
Syntax: hydra [[[-l LOGIN|-L FILE] [-p PASS|-P FILE]] | [-C FILE]] [-e nsr] [-o FILE] [-t TASKS] 
[-M FILE [-T TASKS]] [-w TIME] [-W TIME] [-f] [-s PORT] [-x MIN:MAX:CHARSET] [-c TIME] 
[ISOuvVd46] [service://server[:PORT][/OPT]]
```

What am i doing wrong?
I am using Hydra V9.0 on MacOS Mojave. 
This is the [writeup](https://github.com/madstersogoo/Security_Writeups/blob/master/TryHackMe/hydra.pdf) I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the directory for the login form.
Try this instead:

```
hydra -l molly -P [wordlist directory] [IP] http-form-post "login/:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F=incorrect" -V
```

This shall work.